# Windows 10 - Cannot login to any mail client

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-10

I recently upgraded to windows 10 in my laptop. All has been smooth. But i cannot login to mail, store or calendar using mail accounts. What happens is,

Start/mail/add account/ then the "choose an account" option pop up. But what ever option i clicks (except google), it opens a window for mili-second and closes. The mouse pointer change to working mode but when i move it goes back to normal. When i click google i get a error (0x80040154)

I managed to log in to skydrive using my email. But not mail, calendar or store.